# Trying to compare files opened using 'with open...' in Python 2.4 gives a SyntaxError

Tags: python, file, with-statement, python-2.4, difflib

How can I compare two files in Python 2.4.4?  The files could be different lengths.

We have Python 2.4.4 on our servers.  I would like to use the `difflib.unified_diff()` function but I can't find examples that work with Python 2.4.4.

All the versions that I have seen on Stack Overflow contain the following:

```
with open("filename1","r+") as f1:
  with open ("filename2","r+") as f2:
    difflib.unified_diff(..........)
```

The problem that I have is within version 2.4.4 the `with open ...` generates a SyntaxError.  I would like to stay away from using the system call to diff or sdiff is possible.

Comment: Please upgrade from 2.4.4. If you're about to say "that's up to the server host", please hire new server hosts. If you're about to say "my employer likes it this way", please seek new employment.

Comment: 2.4.4 is really old ... that said you can do `f1,f2 = open("fname1.txt"),open("fname2.txt")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `with` statement was [introduced in Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-343-the-with-statement). It's straightforward to do what you want without it, though:

**a.txt**

```
This is file 'a'.

Some lines are common,
some lines are unique,
I want a pony,
but my poetry is awful.
```

**b.txt**

```
This is file 'b'.

Some lines are common,
I want a pony,
a nice one with a swishy tail,
but my poetry is awful.
```

**Python**

```
import sys

from difflib import unified_diff

a = 'a.txt'
b = 'b.txt'

a_list = open(a).readlines()
b_list = open(b).readlines()

for line in unified_diff(a_list, b_list, fromfile=a, tofile=b):
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

**Output**

```
--- a.txt 
+++ b.txt 
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
-This is file 'a'.
+This is file 'b'.

Some lines are common,
-some lines are unique,
I want a pony,
+a nice one with a swishy tail,
but my poetry is awful.
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I actually messed around with the other difflib options and the format that you provided and found that the following gave a better output:
for line in context_diff(a_list, b_list, fromfile=a, tofile=b):